# How do I enable hibernation on Ubuntu 22 on a LUKS system disk with a swapfile?

Tags: encryption, hibernate, lvm, luks

I have an Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS desktop.  The only swap is a swap file (I removed the swap partition that came as default with the instalation).  I followed [these instructions](https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2021/08/enable-hibernate-ubuntu-21-10/) to enable suspend to disk, and it works.  However, when I reinstall Ubuntu this time with a LUKS encrypted partition, it doesn't.  Instead, hibernation behaves like shutdown.  That's to say after performing `systemctl hibernate`, switching the machine back on leads to a fresh desktop with nothing still open.

On the LUKS encrypted system disk, `blkid` shows two entries, and I've tried with both UUIDs in /etc/default/grub, as per the above linked instructions.

What's the right way to do this?